# How to use svg.checkIntersection()

Tags: svg

I created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89wutc6m/2/) for a test on the `checkIntersection` method from the SVG API.

I don't know whether I am missing something or the method is not working as expected. The test shows 8 times false for me. I would expect at least 2 intersections, ignoring the edge cases.

Any help will be appreciated. Cheers.

UPDATE: I've been testing with Chrome 43.

Comment: As of now you'd be better off without `.checkIntersection()` and its ugly sister `.getIntersectionList()`. If browsers implement these functions, there are multiple bug reports: See [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370012) & [WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81137). FF is completely [missing](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501421) support, while IE seems to have the best implementation.

Comment: @altocumulus Good to know. Very valuable information. Thank you.

Comment: Until this is implemented correctly, I am using the libraries from http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/index.htm and they work flawlessly so far.

Comment: **DO NOT USE the `svg.getIntersectionList` function!** I have absolutly different results in IE10 and in new Opera. In Opera it is very wrong: for triangles and for all shapes and paths they take a rect. In IE is correct: triangles are triangles, paths – paths and only rects – rects. See my **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzZbKp)** for demo. See **[bugs report list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32440892/9801830#comment52754038_32440892)** for Chrome, WebKit and FF(completely missing support) from @altocumulus above.